# PHP only cascading dropdown menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, cascade

I'm defining three arrays:
    $petTypeEntries = array();
    $petTypeEntries[1]='Dog';
    $petTypeEntries[2]='Cat';

And two more that are dependent arrays $dogBreedEntries and $catBreedEntries that list a bunch of breeds for each type.

I have the following predefined function:

```
function selectEntry($display,$name,$nameLabel,$options,$errors,$selected=0)
{
$returnVal = "<li>              
             <label for='$name' class='$nameLabel' id='$nameLabel'>$display: </label>
             <select id='$name' name='$name' required>
                <option value='0'>Choose one...</option>";
                foreach ($options as $key=>$option)
                {
                    if ($key == $selected)
                    {
                        $returnVal .= "<option value='$key' selected>
                                    $option</option>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $returnVal .= "<option value='$key'>
                                    $option</option>";
                    }
                }
                $returnVal .= "</select>
                    </li>";


    if (array_key_exists($name,$errors))
    {
        $returnVal .= addErrorRow($name,$errors);
    }
return $returnVal;
}
```

In my form presentation function, I have this:

```
echo selectEntry('Pet Type','PetType','PetTypeLabel',$petTypeEntries,$dbEntries,$errors);
echo selectEntry('Breed','Breed','BreedLabel',$dogBreedEntries,$dbEntries,$errors);
```

I need to make the options for the breed dependent upon the selected Pet Type.
I know how to do this with standard JavaScript when the form is already present in the html of the page, but I don't know how to tie that in to this type of php form presentation functionality.
If there was some way to utilize standard js functionality to fill in the secondary cascading menu while maintaining the necessary php, I'd appreciate the assistance.

Comment: PHP is server-side. If you want a PHP-only cascading menu, you'll have to generate the entire menu at the same time the rest of the page is being build. A proper client/sever menu would only request the cascaded bits via AJAX on-demand, but that'd be using server-side php and client-side javascript.